# conflict between position:fixed and margin: auto (margins in general)

Tags: html, css

The code I'm working on is in http://jsfiddle.net/truxx/v8jnyn9h/

I would like to make everything that is in the header tag fixed (that it does not move when i scroll the site).

I found out that a code like:

```
div#header{
 position:fixed;
}
```

does that, but it sends the header to the left, and I want it centered.

If I type

```
div#header{
margin:auto;
position:fixed;
}
```

the margin doesn't work at all... how should I correct this?

(I would also like to add a bar in the right of the page, that does not move either while i scroll down. Made an experiment, but something similar happened. The elements of that div box did get a fixed position, but they moved to the left, so i'm guessing it's the same problem).

Comment: There's no id header in your jsfiddle. It's also too much stuff going on that is not relevant to the question. You should provide simple samples when posting questions. Please see: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

This should work for the css:

```
div#header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  margin: auto;
  //AND A WIDTH PROPERTY (in pixels, percent, or em) LIKE:
  margin: 100%;
  }
```

You need to fix it to the top, as well as margin: auto to center. I couldn't find the header element in your code in the link provided, but if you code the rest correctly, that should work.

Comment: For the bar on the right, you should be able to use `right: 0px;`.

Answer (score 0):

Your header (which isn't in your fiddle or your question) will need a width, and top:0;

```
div#header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  margin: auto;
  width:100%; /*or whatever width you want */
}
```